# why add_footnote not working using kableextra in r-markdown pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, kableextra

I'm trying to add footnote under my table but foot note is not getting displayed.

```
kbl(dataf,format="latex",longtable = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position","repeat_header"),bootstrap_options = "bordered",full_width = F)%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T)%>%
  add_footnote("klvnkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk",notation="number")%>%pack_rows("Group 1", 4, 5)
```

Comment: How are you writing this to pdf? With html I can view the footnote `kbl(mtcars,format="html",longtable = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position","repeat_header"),bootstrap_options = "bordered",full_width = F)%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T)%>%
add_footnote("klvnkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk",notation="number")%>%pack_rows("Group 1", 4, 5)`

Comment: i'm working with rmarkdown pdf ,```foot_note``` works